# GTKmm Simple example compiling error

Tags: c++, gtkmm

I am trying to compile simple example from Gtkmm book. The code that I am using is in simple.cc file

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
auto app =
Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv,
  "org.gtkmm.examples.base");

Gtk::Window window;
window.set_default_size(200, 200);

return app->run(window);
}
```

and I try to compile it from command line in following way

```
g++ -o simple.o simple.cc `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

from which I get following errors:

```
simple.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
simple.cc:5:8: error: ‘app’ does not name a type
auto app =
     ^
simple.cc:12:10: error: ‘app’ was not declared in this scope
return app->run(window);
       ^
```

I am using Linux Mint 17.3 and have gtkmm 3.10.1 installed.

Comment: Try adding `-std=c++11`

Comment: @marco-a Thank you a lot, that have solved my problem.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll make that an answer.

Comment: it seems to work without "org.gtkmm.examples.base", why would i wanna type that extra stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable C++11 (or higher) in order to use `auto` and type deduction.

Add

```
-std=c++11
```

to your compilation command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use C++11 you can fully specify the type for app as well.

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app =
    Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
```